Http only cookies disappear after page reload
I'm trying to create http only cookies for my frontend, from my vercel backend using ES modules.
But the problem is when I click on the button, I cam see that there is a cookie stored in the storage tab under cookies. But then when I reload the page, it disappears...
I don't understand. I have tried fixing the issue for 6 hours now. I hope someone can help me.
Some information:
Backend amd Frontend have dofferent domains
Both run on https
Frontend:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Cookie Setting</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="testButton">Test Cookie Setting</button>
    <script>
        async function testCookieSetting() {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('https://xxxxxxxxxx.vercel.app/api/testcookie.js', {
                    method: 'GET',
                    credentials: 'include',
                    mode: 'cors'  // Add this line
                });
                const result = await response.json();
                console.log(result);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('testButton').addEventListener('click', testCookieSetting);
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Backend node.js with vercel:

import cookie from 'cookie';



export default function handler(req, res) {

    // Set CORS headers

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'myfrontend.com');  // Adjust as needed

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');  // Allow credentials



    // Handle OPTIONS request (preflight)

    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {

        res.status(204).end();

        return;

    }



    // Handle GET request

    if (req.method === 'GET') {

        // Create a cookie with a specific expiry date (e.g., September 15, 2024)

        const expires = new Date('2024-09-15T12:00:00Z').toUTCString();

        const cookieHeader = cookie.serialize('testCookie', 'testValue', {

            httpOnly: true, 

            secure: true,   

            sameSite: 'None',

            expires: new Date('2024-09-15T12:00:00Z'),

            path: '/'

        });



        res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookieHeader);

        res.status(200).json({ success: true });

    } else {

        res.status(405).json({ error: 'Method Not Allowed' });

    }



}

I also tried it without the cookie module, and it still didn't work. Even tho it sends a 200 response. And in the response headers I cant find "Set-Cookie"..
So like I said, I have been trying 6 hours now and tried everything possible. Only creating normal cookies via javascript worked..
For what I need it: I have an Github oauth flow and after it retrived the access token and the github username, it also generates a unique identifier (a 49 long random string). All those information get saved on a database, but sl they can be retrieved later, the unique identifier needs to be saved on the client side securely, so ut can be used later to retrieve the right row with the right access token and github username..
If someone has a smarter and better way to later retrieve the values from the database, I'm open to hear them :)
